# How to check a character font and replace it in Microsoft Word Add-In?

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I want to create an add-in for Word to convert between Vietnamese character sets but I don't how to scan each character in document and check its font to convert (there are many charsets and fonts in VN) after has converted I want to replace origin character with the converted character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered here: [How can I loop through every letter in MS Word using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396825/how-can-i-loop-through-every-letter-in-ms-word-using-vba/2397031#2397031)

Comment: Thank for your help. I'll try it. Can I have once more question? Your method can be use on VSTO? Thank a lot!

Comment: absolutely, it would almost be identical in VB.NET with VSTO, but with the interop statements.

Comment: Thank for your help! Can you give me some guides to convert to VSTO? (I'm working with C# and VBA for years, I'm new to VSTO). Thank

Comment: you can open up a new question on how you can get started with VSTO and how VBA converts in general. but why did you change your accepted answer from mine to yours?

Comment: Sorry! Forgive me, I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't know all functions. Again, thank for your help

Comment: no problem. you can visit this question and answer for more details on VSTO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063866/beginning-vsto-development/2064899#2064899